# Поиск по массиву с выводом результата

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с итерируемыми объектами `results`

Перебираю его в цикле

`for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {results[i].Label;}`

Есть поле с инпутом ввода

`var input = document.getElementById("input");`

Забираю веденное значение 
`var val_input = input.value.toString();`

Ближе к делу
Теперь нужно сравнить полученную 
строку с ключом (полем) `i` - го объекта
Т.е  `val_input = = results[i].Label`
и получить искомый `i` - й объект, т.к его остальные ключи необходимы для формирования маркера вывода

Сама проблема в корректном получении `i` - го объекта  тк сравнение получается строгое
и если  в поле `results[i].Label` строка с маленькими или большими буквами либо начинаться с пробела (а то и двух) то вывести не получается.

Comment: У [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) куча полезных методов, почему бы не воспользоваться ими?

Comment: Да вот только мне хотя бы получить искомый объект на такое соотв-е    Например в инпуте var a = "dima"  а в итерируемом объекте  var b = "dimas"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: как ты хочешь определять равенство строк? На сколько они должны отличаться чтобы быть разными?